# Using parse.com and ExpressJS, how would we get Parse.Cloud.Run() to call it's callbacks consistently

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform

Using parse.com and ExpressJS, how would we get Parse.Cloud.Run() to call it's callbacks consistently?

e.g. the below success callback is sometimes called but usually it's not called.  The input data is identical in every execution.

Executing this call to a Parse Cloud Code Function named "getData" I can see in the console logs in parse.com that the Parse Cloud Code function was called and got the correct resulting data.  The only thing that's not working is that the success or error callback functions are rarely called.

The ExpressJS code in app.js is

```
app.get('/open', requireUser, function(req, res)
{
  Parse.Cloud.run('getData', {'AObjectId':'12345', 'BObjectId':'98765'}, {
    success: function(foundObject) {
       console.log('foundObject.value=' + foundObject); //this statement is called about 1% of the time
    },error: function(error) {
       console.log('Failed: 1218' + error.message ); 
    }
  });
});
```

In each execution, the data passed to the Parse cloud function is identical and the data in the Parse classes are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if eval() is used to execute code that has async functionc calls, then the result/return value of the eval() will "not" be the return value of the async function call.  The return value will always be a generic object with this as the JSON value {"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}

For example, a string variable named myCode contains the text to call a function asynchronously, the function will be called, and the success/error callbacks will also be called.  But the result of the call can't be retrieved by the caller if the caller is using eval() to execute myCode.

```
var myCode = "Parse.Cloud.run('getData', {'AObjectId':'12345', 'BObjectId':'98765'}, { success: function(foundObject) { console.log('foundObject.value=' + foundObject); },error: function(error) { console.log('Failed: 1218' + error.message ); } });";

var result = eval(myCode);
```

result will be an object.  And JSON.stringify(result) will be {"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]} instead of foundObject or error.  We were hoping eval(myCode) will return either foundObject or error, then we can perform other logic based on the value of result.  So to solve this problem, in the success callback where we're calling console.log('foundObject.value=' + foundObject); we just call another function to save the foundObject in a database so that later on in the algorithm after eval(myCode) is complete, we can query the database to get the foundObject out.